# ElementCollection with OneToOne inside doesn't cascade "remove"

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I got a model set up as follows:

```java
@Table(name = "parent")
@Entity
public class Parent extends IdEntity {

  @ElementCollection(fetch = EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(
          name = "foo",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  )
  private List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Embeddable
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = ALL)
    private Bar bar;
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends IdEntity {

    private String baz; // marked as unique in the DB
}
```

On every update of a `Parent` instance, I get an exception saying there is a duplicate `Bar→baz` entry.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [bar.baz]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I clean the `foos` collection manually and re-`addAll` the `Foo` entries on every update.

My understanding is that due to the nature of `ElementCollection`, it cascades all the operations and removes the orphans. Since I have a `cascade = ALL` on `Foo→bar` then that should mean that all those entries would get removed and readded as well. What might be causing the "duplicate entry" error then?

Comment: Why do you map this as an ElementCollection? ElementCollection is usually used only with non-entities

Comment: It's not exactly my decision. Legacy project. There's also a couple more fields in the Foo object so I don't think it's really possible to change it now. @SimonMartinelli